# How to call 'time_ago_in_words' from a FunctionalTest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionviewhelper

I'm using 'time_ago_in_words' function in a view, and I need to test the output in the FunctionalTest.

But the test can not see 'time_ago_in_words' helper function.

What should I do in order to use these helper methods from FunctionalTests?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Include the `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` module in your `test_helper.rb` or `test.rb` files. And that's it, from the test console:

```
>> time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)
NoMethodError: undefined method `time_ago_in_words' for #<Object:0x3b0724>
from (irb):4
from /Users/blinq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p376/bin/irb:15:in `<main>'
>> include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
=> Object
>> time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)
=> "3 minutes"
```

Comment: Argh, that really threw me for a loop, sheesh, I had this code in an initializer file and it couldn't find the method. Thanks!

Comment: From the console, you can also access helper functions with `irb(main):110:0> helper.time_ago_in_words 3.minutes.ago`

Comment: @jpemberthy, including this within a model in production can cause performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

I added on `rails_helper.rb`

```
config.include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
```

and work's, thank's @jpemberthy!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently where I was trying to access this function from an API so I wrapped it in a gem called timeywimey. Check it out: https://github.com/onetwopunch/timeywimey#usage

It allows you to access this helper from anywhere in a Rails project as well as Sinatra, and a native ruby project.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly are you trying to test? You shouldn't need to verify the behavior of `time_ago_in_words` itself, because that's covered by Rails' own tests. If you're testing one of your own helpers that uses `time_ago_in_words`, the output can be checked in a helper test (which inherits from `ActionView::TestCase`).

Functional tests are intended for verifying the behavior of controllers (what template they render, whether they allow access, redirect, etc) which can include checking for the *presence of* certain HTML tags (by id). I usually try to avoid using them to check the *content of* the tags.